# load content into iframe from external domain

Tags: iframe

I've been on the web for hours trying to figure out how to load a url within a iframe from and external domain.  presently I have the SRC pointing to the default page: http://playhorseranch.com/link-directory/  the iFrame NAME: le

I want exchange link instructing the user to install my link that loads a deep-link within that frame, as opposed to the home page, or default page I mention.  I thought that ONCLICK might work, but the browser is preventing the external source from manipulating my page.

So now I'm thinking PHP:

http://playhorseranch.com/link-directory?page=http://playhorseranch.com/le/index.php or something.  Hope this sends an e-mail once answered!

~  Jatslo

Answer (score 0):

You can make html iframe by this

```
<iframe scr="http://myurl.com/somewhere">

</iframe>
```

You can read more about iframes [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: This is what I have loaded:  <iframe name="le" src="/le/index.php?a=page&id=linkdirectory" height="1000" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" align="center"></iframe>  the src is default;  I need to populate the "le" field from outside the domain:  http://jatslo.com/?site=playhorseranch.com/le/index.php?a=join, for example.  can I use ONCLICK HREF or should I use PHP??????